# Various Adobe Fireworks CS4 queries

Tags: css, graphics, dreamweaver, slice, fireworks

I am new to Fireworks CS4 and keen to learn to use it right but I am having difficulty understanding the whole slicing and exporting mechanism, so that I can also use in Dreamweaver CS4.

What I have is a header banner image where I also have the name of the site to the left of this header banner.

On this same header image, I want to place two buttons (with rollover effects if possible), to the top right area of the header image, with links to another URL.

Now the things that I am unsure how to do are based on the above description are:

1) How can I make the name of the site section only, to the left of the banner as a link to a url when the user hovers over the name part only, the mouse hand turns into a pointer and gets redirected to url

2) The same goes for the two buttons that I have created as two individual symbols?

3) How can I slice the above two queries, so that I can export into Dreamweaver, so that all the required code comes across with all the desired effects, that is, when previewing in Firefox, all hovering on site name and two buttons work as required?

I am unsure how to slice it? Do I have to assign hotspots to the sections? I am unsure how to export it.

Comment: I *think* this is likely to be closed as not programming related. Maybe try over at doctype.com?

Comment: It will be migrated to superuser.com.

Comment: No problems with being moved - sorry, didn't know about the other two sites mentioned here. Do I need to set-up new accounts for these sites or are my credentials passed over?

Answer (score 0):

There is a slice layer in Fireworks. It is always the top layer. It lets you draw shapes over parts of your graphic, which show up in translucent green. When you click on one, you have the option of adding a URL and other parameters of a link. At that point, you have the option of exporting as sliced images, an HTML page, etc. If exported as HTML, the images will be contained in anchor tags with the URLs you gave them. Or you can just export the slices and assign the links in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Thanks Robusto. I am still unsure about the "It lets you draw shapes over parts of your graphic, which show up in translucent green". I basically have a header image and then want to place to other images on top of this header image. Do I need to slice separately or can I slice all three images together?